# How to wait for sms send confirmation and then send next sms Android

Tags: java, android

I had to send 5-10 messages using,

```
 SmsManager smsManager= SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,messageTosend,null,null);
```

but condition is that i need to confirm each message send success so that i can proceed further sending rest of messages and so on till all.
I know how to listen for success using broadcast Receiver but don't know how to pause further message sending till broadcast notification.

```
 final BroadcastReceiver sendSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Generic failure",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No service",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Null PDU",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Radio off",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
```

How to suspend execution of sendsms code till first sending of sms is a success?

Comment: Place your call to `sentTextMessage()` in the OK case of your receiver

Comment: circumstances are such that i can't do that because those messages can't be accessed in inner class and other issues

Comment: @vincrichaud will this broadcast receiver be listening for the message that i have sent from my app or it may also be triggered on other app that also send sms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean isChecked = true;
final BroadcastReceiver sendSMS = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    while(isChecked == true){
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Generic failure",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isChecked = false;
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No service",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isChecked = false;
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Null PDU",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isChecked = false;
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Radio off",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            isChecked = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Create a while for cheaking if the message is correct and you want to continue, or if it is false.

Comment: I think i shall have to do this in separate thread other than main UI thread as while loop will block execution and app crash may occur. What you say ?

Comment: I had try this solution. It is good but there is a problem with it. The broadcast receiver run only for a single sms. I need to extend it's life how to do that? All i want to say is that the Receiver code run once but  i need to send 100 of messsages

Comment: problem solved i had re-registered the broadcast receiver in recursive fashion in OK of switch